# How to use Twitter Bootstrap popovers for jQuery validation notifications?

Tags: jquery, validation, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I can make popovers appear using [bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap) easily enough, and I can also do validations using the standard [jQuery validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) or the [jQuery validation engine](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine), but I can't figure out how to feed one into the other.

I think what I need is some hook which is called by the validator when it wants to display a notification, give it a closure that passes the message and the target element to a popover. This seems like a kind of dependency injection.

All nice in theory, but I just can't figure out where that hook is, or even if one exists in either validation engine. They both seem intent on taking responsibility for displaying notifications with all kinds of elaborate options for placement, wrappers, styles when all I'm after is the error type(s) (I don't necessarily even need message text) and element it relates to. I've found hooks for the entire form, not the individual notifications.

I much prefer validation systems that use classes to define rules, as they play nicely with dynamically created forms.

Anyone have a solution or a better idea?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Take a look at the `highlight` and `showErrors` [jQuery Validator options](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions), these will let you hook in your own custom error highlights that trigger Bootstrap popovers.

Comment: That's great, thanks. highlight and unhighlight are what I was looking for.

Answer (score 80):

This is a hands-on example:

```
$('form').validate({
    errorClass:'error',
    validClass:'success',
    errorElement:'span',
    highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) { 
        $(element).parents("div[class='clearfix']").addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass); 
    }, 
    unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) { 
        $(element).parents(".error").removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass); 
    }
});
```

[image]

It doesn't really use bootstrap popovers, but it looks really nice and is easy to achieve.

**UPDATE**

So, to have popover validation you can use this code:

```
$("form").validate({
  rules : {
    test : {
      minlength: 3 ,
      required: true
    }
  },
  showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
    $.each(this.successList, function(index, value) {
      return $(value).popover("hide");
    });
    return $.each(errorList, function(index, value) {
      var _popover;
      _popover = $(value.element).popover({
        trigger: "manual",
        placement: "top",
        content: value.message,
        template: "<div class=\"popover\"><div class=\"arrow\"></div><div class=\"popover-inner\"><div class=\"popover-content\"><p></p></div></div></div>"
      });
      // Bootstrap 3.x :      
      //_popover.data("bs.popover").options.content = value.message;
      // Bootstrap 2.x :
      _popover.data("popover").options.content = value.message;
      return $(value.element).popover("show");
    });
  }
});
```

You get something like this:

[image]

Check out the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3qYpM/2/).

Comment: Upvoted because this is in the direction of what I was looking for. :-) See my answer for a variant.

Comment: What to do if it is a multistage form

Comment: Just a quick note that with the latest version of Bootstrap there is not longer a .data("popover") key. Perhaps to avoid collision they have changed the key to "bs.popover". Took me a while to figure out why I was getting an *undefined* error. So now you'll need to use *_popover.data("bs.popover").options.content = value.message;* in the code above.

Comment: How can i display popup on other error type other than required fields. I mean to say how can i customize it to display error only on specific rules.

Comment: There's actually a little problem you can easily check out in the jsFiddle as well. If the field is not required and some rule is broken, the popover shows up BUT if I empty the field and focus on another field, the popover is still there.

The first loop on the successList is never called, so the popover is never in a "hide" state after it gets in a "show" state. Is there anything we can do about it ?

Answer (score 9):

Chris Fulstow had it right, but it still took me a while, so heres the complete code:

This shows the popover on error, and hides the default error labels:

```
$('#login').validate({
  highlight: function(element, errClass) {
    $(element).popover('show');
  },
  unhighlight: function(element, errClass) {
    $(element).popover('hide');
  },
  errorPlacement: function(err, element) {
    err.hide();
  }
}).form();
```

This sets up the popover. The only thing you need from this is trigger: 'manual'

```
$('#password').popover({
  placement: 'below',
  offset: 20,
  trigger: 'manual'
});
```

The title and content attributes passed in to popover weren't working, so I specified them inline in my #password input with data-content='Minimum 5 characters' and data-original-title='Invalid Password'. You also need rel='popover' in your form.

This works, but the popover flickers upon unselecting. Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 6):

Here's a follow up to the excellent suggestion from Varun Singh which prevents the "flicker" issue of the validation constantly trying to "show" even though the popup is already present. I've simply added an error states array to capture which elements are showing errors and which aren't. Works like a charm!

```
var errorStates = [];

$('#LoginForm').validate({
    errorClass:'error',
    validClass:'success',
    errorElement:'span',
    highlight: function (element, errorClass) {
        if($.inArray(element, errorStates) == -1){
            errorStates[errorStates.length] = element;
            $(element).popover('show');
        }
    }, 
    unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        if($.inArray(element, errorStates) != -1){
            this.errorStates = $.grep(errorStates, function(value) {
              return value != errorStates;
            });
            $(element).popover('hide');
        }
    },
    errorPlacement: function(err, element) {
        err.hide();
    }
});

$('#Login_unique_identifier').popover({
    placement: 'right',
    offset: 20,
    trigger: 'manual'
});

$('#Login_password').popover({
    placement: 'right',
    offset: 20,
    trigger: 'manual'
});
```

Comment: This was the only answer on this page that worked for me. Shame it's not been voted up more.

Comment: Doesn't this mean you need to define an explicit `popover` for every single field you want to validate?  If so that's *nuts*.

Comment: For most use cases, I would expect this is perfectly acceptable. If you have a more optimal solution, feel free to add it :)

Answer (score 5):

This jQuery extension for jQuery Validation Plugin (tested with version 1.9.0) will do the trick.

https://github.com/tonycoco/rails_template/blob/master/files/assets/javascripts/jquery.validate.bootstrap.js

This also adds in some Rails-esk error messaging.

Comment: This is great. Super helpful. Now to figure out how to get an appropriate message for a TOS checkbox...

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to change the CSS of bootstrap. Just added the classes of jQuery validate in the right place. field-validation-error and input-validation-error

```
    form .clearfix.error > label, form .clearfix.error .help-block, form .clearfix.error .help-inline, .field-validation-error {
  color: #b94a48;
}
form .clearfix.error input, form .clearfix.error textarea, .input-validation-error {
  color: #b94a48;
  border-color: #ee5f5b;
}
form .clearfix.error input:focus, form .clearfix.error textarea:focus, .input-validation-error:focus {
  border-color: #e9322d;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 6px #f8b9b7;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 6px #f8b9b7;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px #f8b9b7;
}
```

Comment: This approach looks best for me :) . This is also what i was thinking

Answer (score 3):

This is how I did it with Bootstrap 2.x and jQuery Validate 1.9

```
$('#form-register').validate({ errorElement: 'span', errorClass:'help-inline', highlight:    function (element, errorClass) {
        $(element).parent().parent().addClass('error');
    }, unhighlight: function (element, errorClass) {
        $(element).parent().parent().removeClass('error');
    }});
```

Answer (score 3):

Please take a look at the following:
- https://gist.github.com/3030983
I think it's the simplest of all.

**EDIT**

Code from link:

```
$('form').validate({
    rules: {
        numero: {
            required: true
        },
        descricao: {
            minlength: 3,
            email: true,
            required: true
        }
    },

    showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {

        $.each(this.successList, function (index, value) {
            $(value).popover('hide');
        });


        $.each(errorList, function (index, value) {

            console.log(value.message);

            var _popover = $(value.element).popover({
                trigger: 'manual',
                placement: 'top',
                content: value.message,
                template: '<div class="popover"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="popover-inner"><div class="popover-content"><p></p></div></div></div>'
            });

            _popover.data('popover').options.content = value.message;

            $(value.element).popover('show');

        });

    }

});
```

Comment: Many thanks for the heads up! See down my version for Bootstrap but with Tooltips. In my opinion it's more elegant than popovers.

Answer (score 3):

Many thanks for the heads up! Here is my version for Bootstrap but with Tooltips. In my opinion it's more elegant than popovers. I know the question was for popovers so please do not vote down for this reason. Maybe somebody will like it this way. I love when I'm searching for something and I found new ideas on Stackoverflow. Note: no markup on form is necessary.

```
    $('#LoginForm').validate({
        rules: {
            password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 6
            },

            email_address: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            password: {
                required: "Password is required",
                minlength: "Minimum length is 6 characters"
            },
            email_address: {
                required: "Email address is required",
                email: "Email address is not valid"
            }
        },  
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            form.submit();
        },

        showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {

            $.each(this.successList, function (index, value) {
                $('#'+value.id+'').tooltip('destroy');
            });


            $.each(errorList, function (index, value) {

                $('#'+value.element.id+'').attr('title',value.message).tooltip({
                    placement: 'bottom',
                    trigger: 'manual',
                    delay: { show: 500, hide: 5000 }
                }).tooltip('show');

            });

        }

    });
```

Comment: I tried to use your approach, but I was starting to get and error. ant he problem is if you use Jquery UI you will get conflict because both use tooltip. I know there is a solution for that, but just want let others users to know that.

Comment: +1 For jQuery UI heads up! You'll have to configure your custom download (jQueryUI or Bootstrap) to NOT include Tooltip JS functions. It will be a conflict anyway for any tooltip if you failed to do so.

Comment: hey there I was trying to use your code with regex and happen to have an error at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16087351/jquery-validation-regex-for-white-space-getting-a-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-ca/16087452 . Do you think you can help? :)

Comment: @psharma Nothing to do with bootstrap or tooltip. Your error is your rule declaration as you got an answer on your question. the error message said: terms is undefined!

Comment: For some reason, this is the only solution that worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is how I made it happen. But it involves making 2 changes to the validate script (I got the code for bootstrap 1.4 here and then modified it - http://mihirchitnis.net/2012/01/customizing-error-messages-using-jquery-validate-plugin-for-twitter-bootstrap/)

My call to validate:

```
    $("#loginForm").validate({
  errorClass: "control-group error",
  validClass: "control-group success",
  errorElement: "span", // class='help-inline'
  highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
    if (element.type === 'radio') {
        this.findByName(element.name).parent("div").parent("div").removeClass(validClass).addClass(errorClass);
    } else {
        $(element).parent("div").parent("div").removeClass(validClass).addClass(errorClass);
    }
  },
  unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
    if (element.type === 'radio') {
        this.findByName(element.name).parent("div").parent("div").removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
    } else {
        $(element).parent("div").parent("div").removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
    }
  }
});
```

Then you need to change 2 things in jquery.validate.js
1. apply this fix - https://github.com/bsrykt/jquery-validation/commit/6c3f53ee00d8862bd4ee89bb627de5a53a7ed20a
2. After line 647 (in the showLabel function, create label part) after line `.addClass(this.settings.errorClass)` add line: `.addClass("help-inline")`
Someone can maybe find a way to apply the second fix in the validate function, but I havent found a way, since showLabel is called after highlight.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I put in my validate to conform to the Twitter Bootstrap guidelines. The error validation message is put in a `<span class=help-inline>` and we want to highlight the outer container as an `error` or `success`:

```
errorClass:'help-inline',
errorElement:'span',
highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
$(element).parents("div.clearfix").addClass('error').removeClass('success');
},
unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
$(element).parents(".error").removeClass('error').addClass('success');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an update to [Kenny Meyer's excellent answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8675116/4970822). There were a couple of issues that prevented it from working for me, which I have addressed in this snippet:

```
showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {
        $.each(this.successList, function (index, element) {
            return $(element).popover("destroy");
        });

        $.each(errorList, function (index, error) {
            var ele = $(error.element); //Instead of referencing the popover directly, I use the element that is the target for the popover

            ele.popover({
                    trigger: "manual",
                    placement: "top",
                    content: function(){ //use a function to assign the error message to content
                        return error.message
                    },
                    template: '<div class="popover"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="popover-inner"><div class="popover-content"><p></p></div></div></div>'
            });

            //bs.popover must be used, not just popover
            ele.data("bs.popover").options.content = error.message;

            return $(error.element).popover("show");
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the initiative. The code has changed a lot as I can see :-)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is relevant to the discussion because the original poster asked for hooks to show/hide bootstrap popovers.

I was looking for simple validation and popovers didn't matter. A [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713369/twitters-bootstrap-form-validation) and the first in google search results has already been marked duplicate of this question. So it made sense to mention this excellent @ReactiveRaven's jqValidation JS, aptly called jqBootstrapValidation, that weds well with Twitter Bootstrap. Setup takes a few minutes only. Download [here](http://reactiveraven.github.com/jqBootstrapValidation/).

Hope this adds value.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr** avoid needing to enumerate explicit popovers by using a hash map to store the ids of the elements, and creating popovers on-the-fly (mashup Jeffrey Gilbert and Kenny Meyer's approaches).

Here's my take, which fixes the flickering problem mentioned by others, but unlike @Jeffrey Gilbert's answer, does not use a list (`errorStates`) but rather uses an error *map*.  Hash maps FTW.  I think I remember reading somewhere that every problem in CS can be solved with a hash map :)

```
var err_map = new Object();     // <--- n.b.
$("form#set_draws").validate({
  rules: {
    myinput: { required: true, number: true },
  },
  showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
    $.each(this.successList, function(index, value) {
      if (value.id in err_map)
      {
        var k = err_map[value.id];
        delete err_map[value.id]; // so validation can transition between valid/invalid states
        k.popover("hide");
      }
    });
    return $.each(errorList, function(index, value) {
      var element = $(value.element);
      if( ! (value.element.id in err_map) ) {
        var _popover = element.popover({
          trigger: "manual",
                 placement: "top",
                 content: value.message,
                 template: "<div class=\"popover\"><div class=\"arrow\"></div><div class=\"popover-inner\"><div class=\"popover-content\"><p></p></div></div></div>"
        });
        _popover.data("popover").options.content = value.message;
          err_map[value.element.id] = _popover;
        return err_map[value.element.id].popover("show");
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Thanks to all others who posted ideas on this.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this: https://github.com/mingliangfeng/jquery.validate.bootstrap.popover

It shows how to use Bootstrap popover css, instead of JS. JS method popup will cause blinking issue.

Answer (score 0):

If using the above Kenny Meyer code for popups, beware that rules that check a field's content but isn't required such as a valid URL will cause the popup to not disappear upon clearing the field. See below onkeyup for solution. If anyone has a better solution, please post.

```
onkeyup: function(element, event) {
            if($(element).valid())  {
                return $(element).popover("hide");
            }
        }
```