# Twitter's Bootstrap Form Validation

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, validation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use Twitter Bootstrap popovers for jQuery validation notifications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8439490/how-to-use-twitter-bootstrap-popovers-for-jquery-validation-notifications)

Trying to use bootstrap's styles for form validation.

I'm using this javascript validator, that was customized for bootstrap:
https://github.com/ddarren/jQuery-Live-Form-Validation-For-Twitter-Bootstrap

In the head:

```
    <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript">
```

In the body:

```
    <form id="Form" action="" method="post">
      <div class="control-group">
        <input type="text" class="span3" id="Mobile" placeholder="Mobile
          Phone Number" name="Mobile">
      </div>

      <div class="control-group"> 
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Submit
          </button></p>
      </div>
    </form>
```

And it doesn't highlight the fields with bootstrap's error styles. Any ideas where I'm going wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I'm working on something similar so I think I might help you.
First of all, **jQuery-Live-Form-Validation-For-Twitter-Bootstrap** library is quite old (September of 2009).
It uses version **1.3.2** of **jQuery** (the newest is 1.7.1) and it doesn't use the original **Bootstrap** files at all!
If you downloaded **jQuery-Live-Form-Validation-For-Twitter-Bootstrap** (what I am sure you did) from **github** site you can easily check in **css** folder that there are two css files written by the author of that library.
Answering to your question, I downloaded that lib and I've pasted your code and... it works.
 Simply, you need to have in **head** this (and that files in folders):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/jquery.validate.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/style.css" />
<script src="lib/jquery/jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script src="javascripts/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

what is originally taken from **jQuery-Live-Form-Validation-For-Twitter-Bootstrap**.
If you really want to have **Twitter Bootstrap form validation with jQuery** I would like to recommend you using combined [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) and [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation).
I am working on it now and it works perfectly.