# How to ensure if username and password matches with certain value, login button redirects to index.html

Tags: html, css, authentication

How to ensure if username and password matches with certain value, login button redirects to index.html

I believe onclick function handles that. But how and where to add that in the below code. Please guide. Thank you.

I believe onclick function handles that. But how and where to add that in the below code. Please guide. Thank you.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
 <title>Login V9</title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!--==============-->
 <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/icons/favicon.ico"/>
    <!--==============-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!--==========================================-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fonts/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!--==============-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fonts/iconic/css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css">
    <!--================-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/animate/animate.css">
    <!--==============-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/css-hamburgers/hamburgers.min.css">
    <!--==============-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/animsition/css/animsition.min.css">
    <!--==============-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/select2/select2.min.css">
    <!--=============-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css">
    <!--===============-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/util.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
    <!--===============-->
</head>
<body>


 <div class="container-login100" style="background-image: url('images/bg-01.jpg');">
  <div class="wrap-login100 p-l-55 p-r-55 p-t-80 p-b-30">
   <form class="login100-form validate-form">
    <span class="login100-form-title p-b-37">
     App 20
    </span>

    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-20" data-validate="Enter username or email">
     <input class="input100" type="text" name="username" placeholder="username or email">
     <span class="focus-input100"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-25" data-validate = "Enter password">
     <input class="input100" type="password" name="pass" placeholder="password">
     <span class="focus-input100"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
     <button class="login100-form-btn">
      Sign In
     </button>
    </div>

    <div class="text-center p-t-57 p-b-20">
     <span class="txt1">
      Or login with
     </span>
    </div>

    <div class="flex-c p-b-112">
     <a href="#" class="login100-social-item">
      <i class="fa fa-facebook-f"></i>
     </a>

     <a href="#" class="login100-social-item">
      <img src="images/icons/icon-google.png" alt="GOOGLE">
     </a>
    </div>

    <div class="text-center">
     <a href="#" class="txt2 hov1">
      Sign Up
     </a>
    </div>
   </form>


  </div>
 </div>



 <div id="dropDownSelect1"></div>

    <!--==============-->
 <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <!--=============-->
 <script src="vendor/animsition/js/animsition.min.js"></script>
    <!--==============-->
 <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/popper.js"></script>
 <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!--==============-->
 <script src="vendor/select2/select2.min.js"></script>
    <!--===========-->
 <script src="vendor/daterangepicker/moment.min.js"></script>
 <script src="vendor/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
    <!--===============-->
 <script src="vendor/countdowntime/countdowntime.js"></script>
    <!--==================-->
 <script src="js/main.js"></script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: There is no onclick attribute in the provided code. Could it be part of `main.js` or one of those other scripts? There are a lot of scripts included but no JS being used directly on this file. Bootstrap has some validation features, but you'll probably need to do some coding. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713369/twitters-bootstrap-form-validation

Answer (score 0):

This is up to you. If this is just a fun website, you can do verification client side in another js file that you link in, or you can put the script inside `<script></script>` tags. However, *checking plaintext passwords is a TERRIBLE idea* and should *under no circumstances* be used in anything public. Easiest method with this route is to just check the username and password against a map.

The better solution is to run this application on a Go webserver or PHP or node.js or what-have-you. In this case you need to properly hash and salt the passwords and store them securely. When a client tries to log in, the check will be done against the hashed and salted version of their password server side, and the client will get a response back indicating success or failure, and possibly setting a session cookie. There are multiple articles about this process, and I'm sure there will be a more detailed answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in different ways. One way is to use form. you can specify the action in form tag and the form will send the all data typed into input fields with that request. That data is in the form of request body. You can write a handler function to validate the data into javascript.

You should keep only one button in form tag because all buttons are by default of type="submit" in form. Or you have to specify other buttons type="button".

This is how i would suggest to do it.

```
<form action="/validateUserNameAndPassword">
    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-20" data-validate="Enter username or email">
        <input class="input100" type="text" name="username" placeholder="username or email">
        <span class="focus-input100"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-25" data-validate="Enter password">
        <input class="input100" type="password" name="pass" placeholder="password">
        <span class="focus-input100"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
        <button type="submit" class="login100-form-btn">
            Sign In
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks Tushar.I made 2 changes exactly as per your code.
1)added form action line & 2)button type="submit"

Then I added below code at bottom, but Sign In button doesn't redirect me to inde.html. Where am I going wrong?

<script language="javascript">
 function check(form)
 {
  /*the following code checkes whether the entered userid and password are matching*/
  if(form.username.value == "userq" && form.pass.value == "passq")
   {
     window.open('inde.html',"_self")/*opens the target page while Id & pw matches*/
   }
  else
  {
    alert("Error Password or Username")
   }
 }