# Simpler/Better way to add ajax validation results using twitter bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use Twitter Bootstrap popovers for jQuery validation notifications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8439490/how-to-use-twitter-bootstrap-popovers-for-jquery-validation-notifications)

I have been using twitter bootstrap in my projects for some time now.  In all my current use cases, the form submission resulted in a full round trip to the server... i.e. no ajax.  Thus it was fairly simple for me to insert 'error' class on the divs and 'help-inline' spans and their text.

Now I am refactoring to support ajax as far as possible.

Now when forms are submitted, based on the response from the server, I have to addClass 'error' and set text for the spans.  I have created a jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/kinjal/ja9gA/35/) to show this.

Repeated clicking on the register button randomly lights up the email and/or the password divs.  This is working... at least it looks to be working.  The random part is to simulate a submission to the server and receiving errors from there.

The structure of the code is:

```
clear the state (remove error class, reset help text, hide help)
send data to server
if any errors show the errors (add error class, add help text, show help)
```

One problem here is that when the number of fields increase, this code will become long.

Are there any other problems, and are there better ways of doing this?

Suggestions *can* include format of response from server to make parsing/processing easier.

Comment: this seems the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8439490/how-to-use-twitter-bootstrap-popovers-for-jquery-validation-notifications.  Can i vote to close my own question?

Comment: Actually it is not duplicate.  I get that validation could be done on the client side, but my use case requires validation to be done on the server side and to display the errors returned.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend using [jquery validate](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) for what you're doing. You're correct to say that the more fields you have the code could get messy the way you are handling it currently.

Once you have included jquery validate, you can simply add rules based on class names. For example you can have.

```
<input name="email" class="required" />
```

and on your submit button, before sending it to the server, you can check to see if the form is valid by simply doing

```
if($('#registerform').valid()) //returns true/false
```

jquery validate comes with some basic validation methods (email validation being one of them)

so you can do

```
<input name="email" class="required email" />
```

This will make sure the field isn't blank and that it is valid email address before submitting it to the server.

Should you need to create more custom methods, you have the option of adding more validation based on class.

In the case of the strength of the password, it looks like [jquery validate also has a method you can add that handles that as well](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-password-validation/).

Comment: based on your response, http://jsfiddle.net/kinjal/tMFNh/10/.  The validations do not trigger immediately and I need to press register button one time.  But I will figure that out.

Comment: check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BCAeK/1/

Comment: The onblur validation does not start happening till register button is clicked at least one time.  Is this correct behaviour?

Comment: scratch that... i was using jsfiddle wrong.  I was not hitting run, just update.

Comment: That is the default behaviour. There is a way you can bind a valid() to each element with a blur event handler. $('#form input').blur(function(){$(this).valid()});