# jQuery validation regex for white space getting a "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined error"

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

Here is my jquery code as per a previous [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15103447/2061688)

```
$('#productId').validate({
     rules: {
         product: {
             required: true,
             term: {regex: /^$|\s/}
         }
     },
     messages: {
         product: {
             required: "A text is much",
             term: "Please avoid spaces"
         },
     },  

     showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {

         $.each(this.successList, function (index, value) {
             $('#'+value.id+'').popover('destroy');
         });


         $.each(errorList, function (index, value) {

             $('#'+value.element.id+'').attr('data-content',value.message, 'title', 'Oops!').popover({
                 placement: 'top',
                 trigger: 'manual',
                 delay: { show: 500, hide: 5000 }
             }).popover('show');

         });

     }

 });
```

What I am trying to do is show a popover if there is white space in the term entered. But every time it gives me the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined
```

I know something is wrong with the regex part. Because the I tried the same code with minLength and it worked well. What am i doing wrong?

P.S I am using twitter bootstrap for popover.

UPDATE: More about the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined ----------jquery.validate.js:504

    $.extend.check ---------- jquery.validate.js:504

    $.extend.element ---------- jquery.validate.js:357
    $.extend.defaults.onfocusout ---------- jquery.validate.js:231

    delegate ---------- jquery.validate.js:317

    (anonymous function) ---------- jquery.validate.js:1184

    jQuery.event.dispatch ---------- jquery.js:3075

    elemData.handle ---------- jquery.js:2751

    jQuery.event.trigger ---------- jquery.js:2987
    jQuery.event.simulate ---------- jquery.js:3302

    handler
```

Comment: In the first `$.each` loop, you reference `value.id`. But in the second, you refer to `value.element.id`. Is this significant?

Comment: I actually referenced the code from - http://stackoverflow.com/a/15103447/2061688

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fix regex in jquery validation plugin with twitter bootstrap popover](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089725/fix-regex-in-jquery-validation-plugin-with-twitter-bootstrap-popover)

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that you should be using `this.errorList` instead of just `errorList` in the second `$.each`. It's also possible that the difference between the two loops in `value.id` and `value.element.id` is significant too.

Comment: I changed it to `this.errorlist` but no chage. Also I dont understand siginificant. As in how? Lastly, i referenced the code from - http://stackoverflow.com/a/15103447/2061688

Comment: Where is the error coming from, exactly? Can you get a backtrace?

Comment: the code on line 504 is `var result = $.validator.methods[method].call( this, element.value.replace(/\r/g, ""), element, rule.parameters );`

Comment: Well, errors within the jQuery source files usually mean you forgot to include some basic parameter...

Comment: i got it figured. though i have a new question at - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089725/fix-regex-in-jquery-validation-plugin-with-twitter-bootstrap-popover . help if you can . thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The structure of the `rules` declaration is as follows...

```
rules: {                       // <- rules:
    field_name: {              // <- name attribute of field                   
        rule_name: parameter,  // <- rule: parameter
        required: true,   // example 1
        min: 30           // example 2
    }
},
```

Now your code:

```
rules: {
    product: {
        required: true,
        term: {regex: /^\s*$/}
    }
},
```

What exactly is `term` supposed to be?  And why is `regex` inside of `term`?

- If `term` is a rule, you can't nest a rule (`regex`) inside of a rule (`term`).
- `term` is not a "built-in" `rule` [as per the documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation#List_of_built-in_Validation_methods).
- `term` is also not a "custom" rule as per your code.
- If `term` is a field `name`, you can't nest a field (`term`) inside of a field (`product`).

This explains your error,

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined"

In other words, the plugin sees `term` as an undefined method.

Assuming your regex is correct, it should be like this...

```
rules: {
    product: {
        required: true,
        regex: /^\s*$/
    }
},
```

Also, remember that if your custom method returns `true`, the field validates, if it returns `false`, the field will fail validation and the error will display.