# Fix regex in jquery validation plugin with twitter bootstrap popover

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

I have this code which shows a popover when there is a white space.

```
$.validator.addMethod(
        "regex",
        function(value, element, regexp) {
            var re = new RegExp(regexp);
            return this.optional(element) || re.test(value);
        });

 $('#validateForm').validate({
     rules: {
         product: {
             required: true,
             term: {regex: /^\s*$/}
         }
     },
     messages: {
         product: {
             required: "A text is much",
             term: "Please avoid spaces"
         },
     },  

     showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {

         $.each(this.successList, function (index, value) {
             $('#'+value.id+'').popover('destroy');
         });


         $.each(errorList, function (index, value) {

             $('#'+value.element.id+'').attr('data-content',value.message).popover({
                 placement: 'top',
                 trigger: 'manual'
             }).popover('show');

         });

     }

 });
```

What happens is, the popover doesnt get destroyed once there is no whitespace. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you should use `new RegExp(regexp)`?

Comment: i am new to js, if there is a better option please suggest one ;)

Comment: Show the _rendered_ HTML of your form please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery validation regex for white space getting a "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined error"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16087351/jquery-validation-regex-for-white-space-getting-a-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-ca)

Answer (score 1):

This regular expression is valid for both white-space and for an empty string.

If you want to match only white-space, you should use this regex: `/^\s+$/`

Answer (score 0):

The structure of the `rules` declaration is as follows...

```
rules: {                       // <- rules:
    field_name: {              // <- name attribute of field                   
        rule_name: parameter,  // <- rule: parameter
        required: true,   // example 1
        min: 30           // example 2
    }
},
```

Now your code:

```
rules: {
    product: {
        required: true,
        term: {regex: /^\s*$/}
    }
},
```

What exactly is `term` supposed to be?  And why is `regex` inside of `term`?

- If `term` is a rule, you can't nest a rule (`regex`) inside of a rule (`term`).
- `term` is not a "built-in" `rule` [as per the documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation#List_of_built-in_Validation_methods).
- `term` is also not a "custom" rule as per your code.
- If `term` is a field `name`, you can't nest a field (`term`) inside of a field (`product`).

Assuming your regex is correct, it should be like this...

```
rules: {
    product: {
        required: true,
        regex: /^\s*$/
    }
},
```

Also, remember that if your custom method returns `true`, the field validates, if it returns `false`, the field will fail validation and the error will display.