# Add arrow to cancel alert to look like popover

Tags: html, css

I have this code:
[image]

How can I make it have that arrow thing at the top:
like this:
[image]

so it can look like a popup?
Here is the styling for it:

```
.div-cancel{
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
    width:200px;
    display:none;
    height:85px;
    font-size:15px;
    padding-top:18px;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px
}
                            <div class="div-cancel" id="cancel101" >
                            <span><span style="background-color: #FAAB20;"><i class="fa fa-exclamation" style="width:25px;color:white"></i></span>
                            Please type in 'CANCEL' to cancel subscription. </span>
                            </div>
```

Comment: See [How to use Bootstrap popover for jQuery validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8439490/how-to-use-twitter-bootstrap-popovers-for-jquery-validation-notifications)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a border around your arrow, using transform on the `::before` pseudo element and some positioning, can get the affect that you want without any added markup.  Just make sure `div-cancel` has it's `position` set to `relative`.

```css
.div-cancel {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
  width: 200px;
  height: 85px;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding-top: 18px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.div-cancel::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -4px;
  left: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  background: #fff;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<div class="div-cancel" id="cancel101">
  <span>
    <span style="background-color: #FAAB20;">
        <i class="fa fa-exclamation" style="width:25px;color:white"></i>
    </span> Please type in 'CANCEL' to cancel subscription.
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/p4h77chL/4/) is the demo.

The Css solution is:

```
.div-cancel {
    background-color: #1E2021;
    width:200px;
    display:block;
    height:85px;
    font-size:15px;
    padding-top:18px;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    position: relative;
    color: #ababab;
}

.div-cancel:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 6px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color: #1E2021;
    left: 10px;
    top: -12px;
}
```

You can use this CSS with the unchanged HTML shown in the question.